# Unable to parse aws cli command major version from a shell script running in a Jenkins job, but why?

Tags: linux, jenkins, aws-cli

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
aws --version | awk '{print $1}' | awk -F/ '{print $2}' | awk -F. '{print $1}'
```

which should return either 1 or 2 per the major version of aws-cli in the Jenkins node that runs this job.

I also tried including the `#!/bin/bash` shebang in the beginning of the code but to no avail.

For some reason, no matter what I try, I'm unable to parse the major version digit from the output of `aws --version`.

This is the output of the job:

```
[workspace] $ /bin/bash -xe /tmp/jenkins1279490794754365723.sh
+ /usr/local/bin/aws --version
+ /usr/bin/awk '{print $1}'
+ /usr/bin/awk -F/ '{print $2}'
+ /usr/bin/awk -F. '{print $1}'
aws-cli/1.16.198 Python/2.7.16 Linux/4.4.0-1012-aws botocore/1.12.188
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I've tried both absolute and relative path's of the relevant commands but no matter what I get the full output of `aws --version` rather than just the parsed output.

Any idea why?

Comment: Looks like `aws` outputs this information on stderr. Does `aws --version 2>&1 | ...` work the way you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update awk/gawk and rerun your script.

Comment: Is there any part of this `awk` usage that you believe is recent?

Comment: I don't know your env. My awk is - GNU Awk 5.0.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0). With this version script works.